# How to do correct Relative Link in reach router?

Tags: reactjs, routes, reach-router

I have Router with 3 components.
***Page1, Page2, Page3*** have common structure with common header and are switched by clicking on tab under this header.
***Page2Card***  should be opened in a new window. And differs from Page2 completely.

```
 <Router basepath={basepath}>
          <App path="/">
            <Page1 path="page1" />
            <Page2 path="page2" />
            <Page3 path="page3" />
          </App>
          <Page2Card path="page2/:cardId" />
          
  </Router>
```

Moreover, **Page2Card** should be opened in a new window. So, `<Link />` isn't suitable.
I use `<a>` to open it.

```
<a href={`page2/:${cardId}`}>Open in a new window</a>
```

Questions:

1. How can I put component as a child inside routing. I tried.  But this way doesn't work. *Page2Card* doesn't open.

```
    <Page2 path="page2" >
      <Page2Card path=":cardId" />
    </Page2>
```

2. Is it true, that I use `<a />` tag, because `<Link />` doesn't have an opportunity to open in a new window?